# Exchange account access blocked by phantom mobile device

Tags: mobile-devices, ip, exchange

I am not able to log into my workplace Exchange account because there is a mobile device accessing my home IP address; this is blocking my Exchange account log in. How can I determine what specific mobile devices are accessing my home IP address?

Comment: The proper place for this question is serverfault, really. I can, however, give you the answer quickly: you can't.

Comment: Contact your it department?